# Pandas insert multi-dictionary into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've a `dictionary` containing multiple dictionaries that I'd like to insert on a `dataframe`, i.e.:

```
{{u'USDT_REP': {'quoteVolume60m': 0, 'last': u'28.21000141', 'close60m': 0, 'close5m': u'28.21000141', 'close30m': u'28.71000004', 'close8h': u'30.17823249', 'quoteVolume30m': u'9.98429023', 'close24h': u'34.5', 'quoteVolume': u'8667.24172620', 'quoteVolume5m': u'6.745619', 'quoteVolume24h': u'21.43307455', 'quoteVolume8h': u'2.03708838'}, {u'USDT_XMP': {'quoteVolume60m': 0, 'last': u'27.5453345', 'close60m': 0, 'close5m': u'28.21000141', 'close30m': u'28.71000004', 'close8h': u'30.17823249', 'quoteVolume30m': u'9.98429023', 'close24h': u'34.5', 'quoteVolume': u'8667.24172620', 'quoteVolume5m': u'6.745619', 'quoteVolume24h': u'21.43307455', 'quoteVolume8h': u'2.03708838'}}
```

I'd like to get something like:

```
Index    quoteVolume60m     last ...
USDT_REP       0          28.21000141
USDT_XMP       0          27.5453345
```

I've tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict)
```

But I get :

```
                     USDT_REP
close24h          34.10010003
close30m          28.99999805
close5m                 28.21
close60m                    0
close8h           30.17823237
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Try with `from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution should be using `orient` parameter in `from_dict` function call.

As stated by the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

> orient : {‘columns’, ‘index’}, default ‘columns’
>
> The “orientation” of the data. If the keys of the passed dict should be the columns of the
>   resulting DataFrame, pass ‘columns’ (default). Otherwise if the keys
>   should be rows, pass ‘index’.

So, try using:

```
from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
```